# NoSuchMethodError SpringBoot started failed

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I am trying start a Spring boot application on a Tomcat 7. But I got this stacktrace below :

```
ERROR 5236 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Application startup failed

    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/type/AnnotationMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;)V
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport$1.<init>(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:67) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.6.RELEASE.jar:1.4.6.RELEASE]
```

Main.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OssApplicationInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplication(OssApplicationInitializer.class).run(args);
    }
}
```

Someone have an idea for resolving this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Spring Boot 1.4.6. You are getting this error 
, since you're mixing Spring Boot 1.4 and 1.5.  I recommend upgrading to Spring Platform which is based on Spring Boot 1.5.x. You could also downgrade to Spring Boot 1.4.x but I would not recommend downgrade.